# Projection issue for recently downloaded S2H and L8C2 images

Tags: coordinate-system, sentinel-2

Is anyone else seeing issues with projection info in recently downloaded S2H and L8C2 images? I am seeing the projection info as:

```
CRS.from_wkt('LOCAL_CS["unnamed",UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]')
```

which gdal has issue recognizing. Nothing has changed in the downloading process, so I'm wondering why I am seeing this projection!